# Jenkins deployment to elastic beanstalk

Tags: docker, jenkins, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

Hello everyone I am new here and have a question regrading Jenkins deployments to AWS Elastic Beanstalk.

Our app currently consists of 3 components that include the front-end, api and an admin tool all of which run on nodejs. I am trying to cut down on our ec2 instances and would like all 3 components dockerized and running on the same elastic beanstalk instance for our dev environment.

My question is .... is it possible to do 3 separate Jenkins deployments (api, front-end & admin) to a single AWS Elastic Beanstalk instance?

Our current Elastic Beanstalk application is running Multi-container Docker and containers are built using dockerrunaws(v2) and docker compose.

If I deploy the api from Jenkins to our Elastic Beanstalk instance it works as expected but if I then deploy the front-end it overwrites the api container and so on.... is it possible for each separate deployment to create a new container on the instance?

Answer (score 0):

**1.Is it possible to do 3 separate Jenkins deployments (api, front-end & admin) to a single AWS Elastic Beanstalk instance?**

**2.Is it possible for each separate deployment to create a new container on the instance?**

1. If you are asking if it is possible to have three separate "modules" deployed independently via 3 different jenkins deployment pipelines then yes.
2. Yes, this can be done without overwriting your containers.

This article is a good place to start if you were wanting to deploy in a multi docker container setup with Elastic Beanstalk.

[Deploying Dockerized multi-container applications to aws with jenkins](https://medium.com/@pavelbely/deploying-dockerized-multi-container-application-to-aws-using-jenkins-833a998ce6ed)